# Lightswitch v1 Desktop Application doesn't work on 64bit client

Tags: 32bit-64bit, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have made a Lightswitch v1 (2011) Desktop application on Visual Studio 2010 Professional. My OS is 32 bit Windows 7 Professional. The application connects to an SQL Server 2005 database, using SQL Server Authentication.
On clients running 64 bit Windows, my application is unable to load data. (It shows the dreaded red-X, that everyone using Lightswitch is all too familiar with).

I was able to [enable tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520105/lightswitch-v1-shows-red-x-and-unable-to-load-data) and get a detailed error message, but still don't know what to do about it.

Error message:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
ApplicationData.ssdl(2,273) : error 0175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.
```

[image: Detailed error]

Can anyone please help me to get my application running on 64 bit PCs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following post helped me solve this:

http://thinksimpleshirin.wordpress.com/2012/01/17/the-specified-store-provider-cannot-be-found-in-the-configuration-or-is-not-valid-error/

> The machine.config file is located at:
>
> - Windows xp – C:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config
> - Windows 7 – C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config
>
> The corrupted Machine.config file looks as following (with 2 ‘DbProviderFactories’ entries):
>   [image]
>
> As it can be seeing there are to tags for ‘DbProviderFactories’:
>   [image]
>
> To resolve this issue, the empty tag needs to be removed and this should solve the problem

So, apparently, installing JDE on Windows 7 64 bit - breaks LightSwitch. Who would've thought?

Comment: The same thing happened again - I spent the better part of the day trying to figure out what went wrong, and once again 64 Bit Win7 with corrupt data due to JDE installation. Finally had this resolved by referring to this post... Glad I documented it!