# How do I run Lightswitch projects in Visual Studio 2015 without any errors?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have created a simple Lightswitch desktop application in Visual Studio, added one table, and one search screen. When I ran it for the first time, it has shown a window with search screen with a red X mark. Hover over, it displays "Unable to load data. Please check your network connection and try loading again."
I've tried searching for lengthy hours with no luck. I've also tried the answers in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520105/lightswitch-v1-shows-red-x-and-unable-to-load-data) without any luck. I have also tried granting permissions of all levels on the working directory of the project. Please help, this is very frustrating as I've expected so much from Microsoft but they failed to troubleshoot their faulty product.

### Additional Information:

I am using Windows 10 Home, i7, 16 GB RAM, Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate with Update 3. I've tried to clean the entire solution and then debug. There is 1 error and 14 warning messages, here's the error:

```
<!--The Development Database is built in the same location - Bin\Data - for all configurations.-->
    <BuildSchema Inputs="@(ServerMetadataFiles)"
                 ServerGeneratedMetadataFiles="@(ServerGeneratedMetadataFiles)"
                 Collation="$(DatabaseCollation)"
                 DatabaseProject="@(_DatabaseProject)"
                 ProjectPath="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
                 OutputDirectory="Bin\Data"
                 SqlExpressInstanceName="$(SqlExpressInstanceName)"
                 ExternalDataSources="@(ServerExternalDataSources)"
                 Condition="'$(SkipBuildSchema)' == ''"/>
```

And here is one of the 14 errors:

> Warning       The element 'PropertyGroup' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has invalid child element 'UseDesignTimeFeatures' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'. List of possible elements expected: 'Property, VisualStudioVersion, MinimumVisualStudioVersion, AdditionalFileItemNames, AllowUnsafeBlocks, AppConfigForCompiler, ApplicationIcon, ApplicationRevision, ApplicationVersion, AppDesignerFolder, AspNetConfiguration, AssemblyKeyContainerName, AssemblyKeyProviderName, AssemblyName, AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile, AssemblyOriginatorKeyFileType, AssemblyOriginatorKeyMode, AssemblyType, AutoGenerateBindingRedirects, AutorunEnabled, BaseAddress, BootstrapperComponentsLocation, BootstrapperComponentsUrl, BootstrapperEnabled, CharacterSet, CheckForOverflowUnderflow, CLRSupport, UseDebugLibraries, CodePage, Configuration, ConfigurationName, ConfigurationOverrideFile, CreateDesktopShortcut, CreateWebPageOnPublish, CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents, DebugSecurityZoneURL, DebugSymbols, DebugType, DefaultClientScript, DefaultHTMLPageLayout, DefaultTargetSchema, DefineConstants, DefineDebug, DefineTrace, DelaySign, DisableLangXtns, DisallowUrlActivation, CodeAnalysisAdditionalOptions, CodeAnalysisApplyLogFileXsl, ....  Miscellaneous Files C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\LightSwitch\v5.0\Microsoft.LightSwitch.targets  19

Comment: Does creating a simple LightSwitch HTML client application produce similar errors?

Comment: Can you paste the output of your trace that the article you reference mentions?

Comment: No trace was generated. I followed the instructions on the second solution in order to get the result on the chosen answer, but I can't find the trace. If only it was available I might have fixed it beforehand.